# Using Firebug Lite (1.2) would you use it in production sites?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebug

I tried to use Firebug Lite (via the bookmarklet and also adding it to one of my web sites).

I seem to get the alert:

> Unable to detect the following script "firebug-lite.js" ... if the
>   script has been renamed then please set the value of
>   firebug.env.liteFilename to reflect this change

Alot. Especially when I try to close the tab. This happens in Firefox, Camino and Safari.

What I'm wondering is, is this ready for use?, or do I need to copy the code, post it locally and hack it? I already checked the documentation, and it was pretty limited.

I was also looking at the mod dates and the site appears to have been relatively idle since mid-2008.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript file rounds out at 77,305 bytes, so I would think you would not want to use it on a production site unless you were using a dynamic language and could output the script conditionally when you need to do debugging.

(i.e. http://www.somefakesite.com/page?debug=true)

As long as you're only including the file in the page when you are actually debugging, it probably doesn't matter where you pull the script from unless it doesn't work correctly, in which case you would have to modify and serve it yourself.